# Ant build script - if condition check with multiple values

Tags: xml, build, ant

I need to compare list of related environments and perform the operation if any of the environment is matching with the passed argument environment. 
The below code compares each value at time. I don't want to write  for each of the environment as i need to perform the same operation of a group of envs.

How can i compare all the environments (DEV1, DEV2, DEV3) together?

```
<if>
<equals arg1=“${env}” arg2="DEV" /> <!-- Need to compare with DEV1, DEV2, DEV3 -->
<then>
    <echo>Dev related env </echo> 
</then>
<elseif>
    <equals arg1="${env}" arg2=“TST” /> <!-- Need to compare with TST, E2E, UAT -->
    <then>
        <echo>Test related env </echo> 
    </then>
</elseif>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would highly recommend avoiding the use of ant-contrib (the 3rd party library that provides if/else blocks, for loops, etc) whenever possible. This sort of thing is best done using target-level conditions and dependencies native to Ant. Here's an example of how this can be accomplished.

```
<target name="build" depends="development,test" />

<target name="init">
    <condition property="DEV">
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="DEV1" />
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="DEV2" />
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="DEV3" />
        </or>
    </condition>

    <condition property="TST">
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="TST" />
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="E2E" />
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="UAT" />
        </or>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="development" depends="init" if="DEV">
    <echo message="Dev related env" />
</target>

<target name="test" depends="init" if="TST">
    <echo message="Dev related env" />
</target>
```

With the above build script, the user simply calls the `build` target.

1. `build` depends on both `development` and `test` so the script will jump to these and check their dependencies
2. They both depend on `init`, which has no dependencies, so the script will proceed to run `init`
3. The property `DEV` is set to true if the property `env` has one of the 3 development values, and likewise `TST` is set to true  if `env` has a test value
4. The script goes back to the `development` and `test` targets, but only runs either one if its respective condition is true

Side note: if your `env` value follows a predictable pattern (i.e. DEV1 - DEV70), you can use the `contains` condition to simplify things.

```
    <condition property="DEV">
        <contains string="${env}" substring="DEV" />
    </condition>
```